# htaccess redirect subdirectory to subdomain pointing to the same location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Yeah .. yet another url rewrite question. Sorry but the solutions I tried didn't work and gave me infinite redirect loops :(

So, we have a directory on 
  example.com/interface/...
and want to redirect it to 
  service.example.com/interface/... (including all folders and files in it)

its physically the same location but example.com will move to another server soon and then interface.example.com will point to the old(current) server
Right now example.com and service.example.com point to the same web home directory (yay for duplicate content huh)

Also .. we have a rule in place

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and I suspect this one is somehow, together with the other rules I tried, causing the infinite loop error because www.service.example.com does not exist (and shouldnt)

I suppose its rather simple but I just can't get my head around rewrite stuff :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new rule for this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^interface(/.*)?$ http://service.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```